# Derived-class constructor names being deprecated in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, syntax

Currently, PHP supports two naming conventions for constructors. PHP 4 supported Java-style constructors:

```
class A
{
    public function A()
    {
        echo "I'm a constructor for class A!";
    }
}
```

PHP 5 supports both the Java-style constructors and a "magic method" syntax:

```
class A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "I'm a constructor for class A!";
    }
}
```

The Java-style syntax is slated for deprecation, and [some features of it don't work in the latest PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). However, it has an interesting property that I know of no analogue for with the "magic method" syntax. If derived class `foobar` has no explicit constructor, then the `foobar` method of the base class becomes the `foobar` constructor:

```
class A
{
    public function A()
    {
        echo "I'm a constructor for class A!";
    }

    public function B()
    {
        echo "I'm a constructor for class B!";
    }
}

class B extends A
{
}
```

Since Java-style constructors are being deprecated, what will become of the set-the-constructor-in-the-parent language feature?

Comment: First, the fact that the inherited `B` method acts as the constructor is probably more of an unforeseen side-effect of how classes were originally implemented, than a feature. Second, when the Java-style constructors become fully deprecated they will simply stop working. I am not giving this as an answer because I feel your question answers itself.

Comment: Looks like more of a bug (PHP looking for a constructor *after* it logically implemented the extension during the compilation process). As a matter of fact, I preferred the Java-style constructor... (without the bugs)

Comment: This is not a bug, in fact it is an explicit feature of PHP that is mentioned somewhere in the fine manual. I'll try to dig it up.

Comment: *Feature?* Why on earth would anyone *want* to do this? If you know that there will be a class named `B` deriving from you then why not place the constructor in `B` itself? In any case, you can achieve the same effect by implementing `__construct` in the parent and using `get_called_class()` to determine what's being instantiated. But *ugh*!

Comment: Can you give a use-case for defining the constructor in the parent? I can't really see it being a useful feature. If I really want to construct `B` using the `B()` method in `class A`, I can always write the constructor for `B` to cal `parent::B()`. I can't see a case where I'd want it to magically pick `B()` as the constructor. In fact, I can see cases where it might cause real confusion.

Comment: @Jon, SDC: Use case? Why on Earth? I don't know, but OOP PHP has lots of quirks. Why don't parent constructors automatically get called, in contrast to other OOP languages that do? Why the 'magic method' syntax, which means that constructors cannot be discussed out of the context of the class (such as in an email)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably learned this [here](http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.constructor.php), for PHP 4.

As you already know, in PHP 5 documentation ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)) it is stated that if no __construct() is used or inherited, the old syntax kicks in as a fallback:

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct() function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a parent class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class. Effectively, it means that the only case that would have compatibility issues is if the class had a method named __construct() which was used for different semantics.

So the old syntax should still be valid, as PHP 5.4.11. There is no explicit plan for deprecation, right now, even if it's foreseeable.

Anyway, when (and if) they will be dropped, this feature will be dropped too as there is no way to reproduce it with the __construct() syntax.

Comment: Regarding the 5.3.3 version: that's when back-compat constructors stopped working for *namespaced* classes. The existing answer is a bit unclear on what the significance of 5.3.3 is.

Comment: You're right, the current stable PHP version is 5.4.11. Let me fix it.

Comment: They'll be deprecated in PHP 7.0 and probably removed in the following major release: http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.deprecated.php#migration70.deprecated.php4-constructors

Answer (score 0):

What PHP installation are you working now ?

If you have a PHP 5 installation:

If you are making new classes, use the new style.
If you already have classes with the previous style, they still work,
but, it good that you update them, when you can.

If you have a PHP 4 installation:

Yopu have to use the previous style. If you change to PHP 5 later,
they also work.

Cheers.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question asked.